# appending svg to a list item dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

For some reason that I can't figure out, when I add item to my ul dynamically using JS, I get first svg appended under it, like in the picture. Then when I add one more item, second one gets aligned smoothly next to a list item, but there is always this one extra at the bottom and I can't track where is it coming from. Pictures:
[image]

[image]

```
<ul id="todo">
<!--<li>Grocery shopping</li>-->

</ul>

<ul id="done"></ul>

ul#todo {
  font-family: "Roboto", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
}

ul#done {
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.check_mark {
  background: url("assets/group.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 20px;
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;*/
  z-index: 99999;
}

(function () {
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var userInput = document.getElementById("user_input");
var entered = false;
function addItem() {
  if (!entered) {
    categorize();
  }
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.id = "item";
  li.innerHTML = userInput.value;
  var item = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);
  var checkMark = document.createElement("div")
  checkMark.id = "check_mark";
  checkMark.className = "check_mark";
  document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(checkMark);
  document.getElementById("item").onclick = function () {
    li.remove();
    checkMark.remove();
  }
    checkMark.onclick = function () {
      var that = this.parentNode.childNodes[2];
      var doneList = document.getElementById("done");
      doneList.appendChild(that);
      /*this.parentNode.childNodes[2].*/
    }


  userInput.value = "";
}

function categorize() {
    entered = true;
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.innerHTML = "to-do";
    document.getElementById("todo").appendChild(h1);
}



button[0].addEventListener("click", addItem, false);



})();
```

https://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/JNbwPE

**EDIT:**

Alright, so I fixed the problem myself, just changed

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(checkMark)
```

to `item.appendChild(checkMark);` but now the problem is that when I click a check mark to move the item to another ul list `#done`, I get error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at HTMLDivElement.checkMark.onclick (script.js:25)
```

I just can't figure out why is this hapenning. Any help? Thanks

Comment: You should not have any other elements than LI under UL

Comment: Oh, so I have h1 inside, I should remove it and put it outside ul element?

Comment: h1 and divs too. outside of ul element or inside li elements. that's the proper usage.